# Typescript: Typeguard Symbol.iterator

Tags: typescript, iterable, typeguards

I’m trying to write a function that accepts either `Iterable<T>` or `AsyncIterable and maps it:

```js
function map<T, U>(
  fn: (item: T) => U,
  items: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>,
): Iterable<U> | Iterable<U> & AsyncIterable<U> {
  async function* asyncMapper() {
    for await (const item of items) {
      yield fn(item);
    }
  }

  if (!items[Symbol.iterator]) {
    return asyncMapper()
  }

  return {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for (const item of items) {
        yield fn(item);
      }
    },

    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: asyncMapper,
  };
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcA8AVANIgVQD4AKYMALkRJigFNkrsBKRAXiMP1oYGcqAgrwCekAJL0ATqgBGAGzo4izQSPFTZCzMQDcAKFCRYCFBhz5iJPYkTkqNeo0Qt2nArmuIeyfogl1peUVsIg8VPw0g7U4AMkQhUQh-QK1dPQNwaHgkNCw8QlJPO2pvJlYOLk9vX2TNYNj4tSTIrRC9cNqo4kQ4hPUAuuj9DKNs0zyLQptihwYy10qbaqpO1s4AH0bE1fr2lZbFbs2+5oGuzgBvT1Qm20zjMAAqRBvEgFkMdACSViubabgkheAHdULRqBAELwoF5HIg4MBYXxfp5-ohhDA6HIACa2MCzZDMfRogC+njJVURJAAhNUANoAZWEyBkcDkADoeNIoICALootGSOhQECSJCvSAfdBfSQ-cnpGxCkVixB-f6PRnM1kcrmoHmSXk-VWo-7AQEQqEw7zwxHVAVo-4YrG48gEokmmxk0keE2alls9kS07cvlUINSmUeT36MlAA)

The gist of it is that, if the items implements `Symbol.iterator` we will return an iterable that can iterate both synchronously *and* asynchronously. However if we don’t we will return only the async iterable.

The problem is that I cannot typeguard the existence of `Symbol.iterator` because of the error:

> **error TS7053:** Element implicitly has an `any` type because expression of type `symbol` can't be used to index type `Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>`.

Does anyone know how to typeguard `Symbol.iterator`, or if I’m doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a user-defined type guard:

```
function isIterable(x: any): x is Iterable<unknown> {
  return Symbol.iterator in x;
}

function map<T, U>(
  fn: (item: T) => U,
  items: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
): Iterable<U> | AsyncIterable<U> {
  async function* asyncMapper() {
    for await (const item of items) {
      yield fn(item);
    }
  }

  if (!isIterable(items)) {
    return asyncMapper()
  }

  return {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for (const item of items) {
        yield fn(item);
      }
    },

    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: asyncMapper,
  };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgSSgUwE4EMBGANpgBQAeAXIrmAJ4CUVZyKiGOBxAPOANZhwA7mAB8iAN4AoRImyYoIbEgDKtALb44hAHQwseKHGzIkZANySAvpMmhIsBIjW4ADlwAqAGkQBVESWAwKhI9TDUqd3pEAF4xH29QtRQqAEEUWkh2PCJMDxFGRDSMiCzOXL8LO2h4JGc3L19-aURA4MSIqNjfT2bE5LZ9MryegtKcrj9EADJC9MzB8YqbKoda1w9vPxJm1sQQrHDESJi4npk+qjHudzEZovmOcZvJUYXuSbu5krfykQtbcDVRx1DaNbYyXb7MIdE7dXoHfpXXI3RAAH1mxSReRelx+EzE6Pu30e7zEUhkuC+LUBqwAVNQvgBZVwuHAkKLkmQtIzUQS4PR7CAIFBQZAHRBwYBisIoDnNLmIWgwTCEAAmLTAULU9AsCusMmsvSlJAAhKgkVrZXKFXIFEoGcVmS5Wdh2c1DTJbYokJyZLSANqqDRaXSDQzYAC67Ik8q5wB5JCFYBF0rUEqlfWtCq5SpV6sCWp1sYNscsPVjgfUmh0lMxYaMEaotcgTpdZ0Qlgs1iAA)